# How to make Hibernate see liquibase inserts?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, liquibase

I have an app where I want to save some entities which have some fields. I used liquibase to add some when the application starts. The problem is that when I try to save a new one Hibernate tries to give to it the id 1 but this id already exists in the database. How can I make hibernate aware of liquibase inserts?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what is your ID generation strategy. If you are using a sequence simply set the initial value of the sequence to 10,000. This will allow you to insert up to 10,000 records with Liquibase.

For example if you are using PotgreSQL you can do

```
ALTER SEQUENCE sequence_name
MINVALUE 10000
START 10000
RESTART 10000;
```

Comment: This is the completely wrong approach. If you are using sequence generator you should read next id from sequence. select SEC_NAME.nextval from dual;